# Add complementary values to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 1D numpy array, for example the following:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0.33, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9])
```

Now I would like to change the array so that also one minus the value is included. That means the array should look like:

```
[[0.77, 0.33],
 [0.8, 0.2],
 [0.2, 0.8],
 [0.1, 0.9]]
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `column_stack`

```
np.column_stack([1 - arr, arr])

Out[33]:
array([[0.67, 0.33],
       [0.8 , 0.2 ],
       [0.2 , 0.8 ],
       [0.1 , 0.9 ]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> np.vstack((1 - arr, arr)).T
array([[0.67, 0.33],
       [0.8 , 0.2 ],
       [0.2 , 0.8 ],
       [0.1 , 0.9 ]])
```

Alternatively, you can create an empty array and fill in entries:

```
>>> np.empty((*arr.shape, 2))
>>> x[..., 0] = 1 - arr
>>> x[..., 1] = arr
>>> x
array([[0.67, 0.33],
       [0.8 , 0.2 ],
       [0.2 , 0.8 ],
       [0.1 , 0.9 ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
arr=np.insert(1-arr,np.arange(len(arr)),arr).reshape(-1,2)
```

---

```
arr
```

Output:

```
array([[0.33, 0.67],
       [0.2 , 0.8 ],
       [0.8 , 0.2 ],
       [0.9 , 0.1 ]])
```